# Alter Youtube Video Page using Chrome Console JS & CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I was wondering if I could adjust the style of some html elmements on a web page using the google chrome console.

I watch podcasts on youtube. And I hate the fact that youtube suggests related videos that are miles ahead in the podcast timeline (i'm trying to catch up). I want to adjust a couple of element styles on the site.

What I want to achieve is to run the following code every time a youtube video page loads:

```
function youtubeVideoPageLoad()
{
    youtubeFunction();
    $('body').on('transitionend', function(event)
    {
        if (event.target.id != 'progress') return false;

        $('#watch7-sidebar-contents').remove();
        $('.html5-main-video').css("width","auto");
        $('.html5-main-video').css("height","auto");
        $('.player-height').css("height","720px");
        $('.ytp-chrome-bottom').css("width","100%");
        youtubeFunction();
    });
}

$(youtubeVideoPageLoad);
```

This removes the suggested videos and makes the video and sub content bigger. Just nicer for me.

How can I make this possible because I get `.css is undefined`. Is this a problem because I cannot use jQuery in the console.

And how could I run this every time a youtube page is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Stylebot is a chrome extension that allows you to apply CSS to any site super easy

Comment: @DelightedD0D nice! Do you use it personally, how do you use it, what purpose do you have for it?

Comment: Of course you do since `$().css` is `jquery`. Either import before you run your code or just use plain js

Comment: @cwiggo I added an answer below to better explain my use of Stylebot. If you're still currious why your jquery doesnt work, can you post a link to a page you are attempting to use this on?

Comment: @DelightedD0D `$` doesn't mean `jQuery`, it's just token substituting `jQuery` for `$`. `$` can be set to anything. Open the source of a youtube video page and search for `jQuery`, you wont find it.

Comment: @rism yeah you're right. Is there anyway you can import jQuery to the console for use on the loaded web page?

Comment: @DelightedD0D i'm just trying to achieve this using the console only.

Comment: @cwiggo see my update

Answer (score 0):

As rism mentioned, If you must do this via the console and using jQuery, you'll need to actually inject jQuery into the page yourself as Google does not use jQuery on the YouTube page.

Here's how:

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
head.appendChild(script);
```

Then you can use jQuery functions like `jQuery.find('div')`.

You still wont be able to use the `$` as YouTube has a different value assigned to `$` already.

---

That said, I use [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) for this type of stuff. It's a Google chrome extension that allows you to add your own CSS to any website. It saves your custom CSS and applies it anytime you open that webpage.

I personally use it to remove unwanted google ad divs and to fix issues with page layouts when I dont own the page (jumpy menus and what not). I also use it to customize our work websites like Atlassian Jira and Confluence. It has worked well for me.

After you install it, there are a few ways to use it. The simplest is to...

**Click the CSS browser action button**

[image]

**Click the "Edit CSS" button at the bottom of the flyout menu**

[image]

**Write your custom CSS in the provided box and click "Save"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what your `youTubeFunction` is supposed to represent so I hope you do. As per comments `$` probably doesn't mean `jQuery` on YouTube and this is conclusion is supported by `console.log($)` output. So best bet is too just use plain javascript as below or condense it into a single line:

```
function youtubeVideoPageLoad()
{
    youtubeFunction();
    var uBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    uBody.addEventListener('transitionend', ytCustomizer);
}

function ytCustomizer(event)
    {
        if (event.target.id != 'progress') return false;
        document.getElementById('watch7-sidebar-contents').style.display='none';
        var vid = document.getElementsByClassName('html5-main-video')[0];
        vid.style.width='auto';
        vid.style.height='auto';
        document.getElementsByClassName('player-height')[0].style.height= "720px";
        document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-chrome-bottom')[0].style.width= "100%";
        youtubeFunction();
    });

youtubeVideoPageLoad();
```